# MVCContrib - Using Html.StyleSheet() Helper Renders Incorrect Path when used with T4MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib

I am using the latest version of MVCContrib and attempting to include a stylesheet via the following helper method:

```
<%=Html.Stylesheet(Links.Content.Site_css)%>
```

The path rendered is incorrectly calculated as:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/content/css/Content/Site.css" />
```

The actual path should be: /Content/Site.css

Is this a bug?

The following methods work correctly:

METHOD 1:    `<%=Html.Stylesheet("~/Content/Site.css")%>`

METHOD 2:   `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<%:Links.Content.Site_css %>" />`

**UPDATE 1:**

Links.Content.Site_css represents a static field that is auto-generated using T4MVC

**UPDATE 2:**
Here is what the code generated by T4MVC looks like...

```
namespace Links {

    ...snipped for brevity...

    [GeneratedCode("T4MVC", "2.0"), DebuggerNonUserCode]
    public static class Content {
        private const string URLPATH = "~/Content";
        public static string Url() { return T4MVCHelpers.ProcessVirtualPath(URLPATH); }
        public static string Url(string fileName) { return T4MVCHelpers.ProcessVirtualPath(URLPATH + "/" + fileName); }

        public static readonly string Site_css = Url("Site.css");
}
```

Comment: What on earth is `Links.Content.Site_css`? A constant? A field? Something else? What's it's value?

Comment: Darin, please see my updated question for clarification on Links.Content.Site_css

Comment: What is the actual value of `Links.Content.Site_css`? If it starts with "~/" the auto-pathing will not be used. It should be equal to `Site.css` if you want the helper to work correctly.

Comment: What Ryan is asking is what this evaluates to, which should be "/Content/Site.css". The question then becomes: why can't Html.Stylesheet deal with this? I'm not familiar with this API (but I own T4MVC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a bug. This works as expected. Refer to [Using MvcContrib ScriptInclude, Stylesheet, And T4MVC](http://elijahmanor.com/webdevdotnet/post/Using-MvcContrib-ScriptInclude-StyleSheet-And-T4MVC.aspx)

> *the output of the T4MVC Links are relative paths that have been resolved (meaning they no longer have the “~”). The MVC Contrib Helpers assume that if the URL passed it it doesn’t have the “~”, then it will prepend either “~/Scripts/” for scripts or “~/content/css/'” for styles.
>   Seeing that I have moved my scripts, styles, and images under the “~/Content” folder, there are a couple of changes to the MVC Contrib Html Helpers that could make this work…
>   Provide some sort of mechanism to define the paths prepended to the Scripts and Styles if there is no “~”
>   Override the Html Helpers with another option to not prepend any path information
>   Possibly search for the “/” instead of the “~” when determining if a path should be prepended to the URL*

Comment: Thanks for the response.  As you mentioned, this issue also occurs with the Html.ScriptInclude() helper.  This seems like a mismatch between MVCContrib and T4MVC (part of MVCContrib) which deserves some consideration in future release.